# Prove $G$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{72} \times \mathbb{Z}_{72}$ and show its order.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a subset of the group $\mathbb{Z}_{72} \times \mathbb{Z}_{72}$ defined by
>   $$
> G:=\{ (17l + 6m, 11l + 6m) : l,m \in \mathbb{Z}_{72} \}.
> $$
>
> (1) Prove that $G$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{72} \times \mathbb{Z}_{72}$.
>
> (2) Prove that $|G| = 864$.(Hint : Use the restriction to $G$ of the projection map $p : \mathbb{Z}_{72} \times \mathbb{Z}_{72} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{72},\ (x,y)\mapsto y$)

So for the first one I tried :

i) Let $l = m = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}_{72}$. Then We have $(0,0) \in G$. So $G \neq \emptyset$.

ii) Let $a = (17l + 6m, 11l + 6m)$, and $b = (17k+6n, 11k+6n)$. Then 
$b^{-1} = (72 - 17k -6n, 72 - 11k - 6n) \in G$. (if necessary, mod out each element by $72$) So we have
$$
ab^{-1} = (17l + 6m, 11l + 6m) + (72 - 17k -6n, 72 - 11k - 6n) \in G.
$$
Also mod out by $72$ if necessary.

For the second, I have no clue.

Am I right?

Comment: Are you sure that $|G| = 864$ ? I get $144$.

Comment: @lhf  I guess so.

Comment: @lhf Indeed, I also get 144.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whith hardly the same effort you used to prove that $G$ is a group, you can prove that the map $\mathbb{Z}_{72} \times \mathbb{Z}_{72} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{72} \times \mathbb{Z}_{72}: (1,0) \mapsto (17,11), (0,1) \mapsto (6,6)$ is an endomorphism. Seen that $G$ is the image of this endomorphism and thus a group. Moreover the kernel of this endomorphism is a solution of the system $$\left\{  \begin{array}{c} 11l + 6m & = & 0\\
17l + 6m & = & 0\end{array} \right.$$ Giving as a solution $(12,50)$ and multiples. This generates a group of order $36$, and by the first isomorphism theorem we have $|G| = \frac{72^2}{36}=144$.